# How to debug a pcmcia-scsi adaptor issue with a slide scanner?

Tags: drivers, devices, scanning

I am looking for ways to debug (or understand why things don't work as I expect with) the initialisation of an SCSI-2 device (Microtek ArtixScan 4000t) using a PCMCIA adaptor (Adaptec SlimSCSI 1450B) on my old P4 Laptop with Ubuntu 9.10.

I use `vuescan` as it is capable of recognising the 4000t - and the author of `vuescan` assures me that it should work.

On insertion in my Ubuntu system, the PCMCIA-SCSI adaptor shows as `Socket 0 Device 0: [aha152x_cs] (bus ID: 0.0)` (`lspcmcia`) and resets the scanner, but vuescan does not detect the scanner and no device shows with `lsscsi` or `lspci`. I tried as root just in case, same story.

I have also tried without success on a Windows XP laptop. Same as above, the adaptor is recognised by the system and the scanner gets reset on insertion of the PCMCIA card, but vuescan does not see the scanner.

Back to Ubuntu, I tried the command `echo "scsi add-single-device 0 0 ? 0" > /proc/scsi/scsi` with `0` and `2` for `?` (having set the scsi device number on the scanner to 0 or 2) to no avail. with 2 it said the parameter was incorrect, with 0 it accepted but did not seem to do anything with it. `/proc/scsi/scsi` is always size 0. I have tried those commands as root, and tried starting `vuescan` both under my regular user and as `root`. In every try so far with the 4000t (and Adaptec SlimSCSI 1450B PCMCIA-SCSI adaptor) `vuescan` does not see any scanner.

I would appreciate any lead that would help me debug or fix this issue.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards